# how to customize OOB web parts UI

Tags: 2013, web-part, javascript, out-of-the-box

SharePoint 2013 brings a new concept of UI customization, via the JSLink, allowing to reconfigure the Web Parts UI aspect/behaviors, as exemplified by O'Brien [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html).

Although, most of SPObjects doesn't support JSLink (check above link), which is understandable, so what are the best way to edit the UI or even extend a minor funtionality on a OOB App/Web Part?

Note: Via coding is also complicated cause in some cases the class is sealed.

Any input/reference is welcome.

Comment: Did you take a look at \15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES ?? Did you tried to modify Corev15.css ? This is what we did before JSLink.

Comment: changing source files is not the approach I'm looking for, and about css, will not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `CSR` was introduced as a default rendering mode in SharePoint 2013, for some web parts, `XSL` based approach is still the only (no code) option available for customizing the rendering.

For example, [Content Query web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart%28v=office.14%29.aspx) supports only server side rendering mode (`XSL`) in SharePoint 2013

To summarize, in SharePoint 2013 you could choose what technique  to use when customizing the rendering for web parts that support both client & server side rendering ,for another web parts you could still use `XSL` based approach.

Comment: CSR is great for ListViews and XSL for Content Query Web Part, but what about if, e.g., i want to change the rendering mode of the OOB 'People' Web Part?

Comment: I guess you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.memberswebpart.aspx ?

Comment: SPSWC:PeopleWebPart - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.peoplerendererwebpartbase(v=office.15).aspx